# When and how do I need to set the "paths" property in a build configuration for r.js?

Tags: build, requirejs, r.js

I am making a build configuration for `r.js`.

The configuration that I use has been defined in the `main.js` file using `require.config({...})` and has been reference like below in the start page(html)

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/lib/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also there is no reference of any script from CDN, all the modules and there dependencies are local.

If I am specifying the `"mainConfigFile"` property to the `main.js` file of my application that has the information about which module to load and it's dependencies, then do I need to explicitly set the `"paths"` property?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions in this question, so to address them separately:

1. Do I need to set `paths` in my `r.js` build configuration in addition to those in my run time configuration that a point to with `mainConfigFile`?

   Maybe. It depends on your specific application.
2. Why would I need to set it?

   You need to set it if you want to override the `paths` that you set in your run time configuration. A common use-case scenario is when you specify files to be loaded from a CDN in your rum time configuration. You *must* set those paths to `empty:` in your build configuration.
3. How would I do it?

   Taking the example of the CND, if `jquery` is set to load from a CDN in the run time configuration, then the build configuration would contain:

   ```
   paths: {
       jquery: "empty:"
   }
   ```

You say:

> In my project there is no runtime configuration. The only configuration that I use has been defined in the `main.js` file using `require.config({...})`.

The configuration you pass to `require.config` **is** your run time configuration. So you do have one.

Comment: Thanks Louis for the response. Based on your answer I have improvised my question for better understanding. Please have a look.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You said you don't use a CDN. Fair enough, but what am I supposed to do with this information? I don't have a crystal ball to determine whether there are *other* reasons in your application to override paths in the build configuration.